# How to replace all the first occurences in matched lines with incremental number?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, replace

I have a file like this

```
...
1562 first part
1563 H     col3 H col4
1564 H     col3 H col4
...
3241 H     col3 H col4
3242 third part
...
```

I want to replace only the first `H` in every line to `H#`, with `#` is its number of appearance. The output should be:

```
...
1562 first part
1563 H1    col3 H col4
1564 H2    col3 H col4
...
3241 H1652 col3 H col4
3242 third part
...
```

So far, I've tried:

```
max=`grep -c ' H ' b`
while [[ "$i" -le $max ]];do
  grep -m $i ' H ' b|tail -n1|sed "s/H/H$i/1"
  let i=i+1
done
```

This code is slow, it needs to read every line to replace and can't add the first part and third part of the file. Is there any better way to do this? Maybe awk? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can for example use this:

```
$ awk '/H/{sub("H", "H"++v)}1' file
1562 first part
1563 H1     col3 H col4
1564 H2     col3 H col4

3241 H3     col3 H col4
3242 third part
...
```

This looks for those lines containing `H` and replaces that `H` with `H` together with a variable we keep incrementing. Note you could use `gsub()` instead of `sub()` if you wanted to perform this change in all the matched patterns instead in just one.

The final `1` is a true condition, hence it performs the default awk action: `{print $0}`, that is, prints the full line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  awk 'BEGIN { hNum = 1; } { if ($2 == "H") { $2 = "H" hNum; hNum++; } print $0; }' yourFile > outFile
```

It run `awk` using space as separator, so `$2` is the second token of each line and if `$2` is equal to "H", then replace it with "H" followed by number started from 1. Finally print out line.

Comment: this works, however it makes the line unsorted.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\bH\b\K/++$i/e' file
```

You can replace `-pe` with `-pi.back -e` for in-place editing with the original saved as `file.back` or `-pi -e` for no backup.

Comment: What's the use of e modifier?

Comment: @AvinashRaj `e` to `e`valuate the substitution part as `perl` code.

Answer (score 1):

```
{   nl -bpH -w1 |
    sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)[ \t]*\([^H]*.\)/\2\1/'
} <<\DATA
...
1562 first part 
1563 H     col3 H col4
1564 H     col3 H col4
...
3241 H     col3 H col4
3242 third part
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
...
1562 first part 
1563 H1     col3 H col4
1564 H2     col3 H col4
...
3241 H3     col3 H col4
3242 third part
```

That's the fastest way I can imagine it would be done - especially with a very large file. `nl` will number only lines containing the string *H* and insert that number at the head of the line followed by a `<tab>` character. It indents all other lines with a few spaces.

`sed` is passed `nl`'s output over the `|`pipe. `sed` then replaces the following sequence:

- 0 or more digits occurring at the beginning of the line *(referenced as `\1`)*
- 0 or more `<tab>` or `<space>` characters
- 0 or more characters that are not H then one character *(referenced as `\2`)*

...with `\2\1`.

So lines not containing an *H* get this treatment:

```
^''   .*.$ = ^.*.''$
```

And those that do get this one:

```
^(digit)*<tab>(not H)*H.*$ = ^(not H)*H(digit)*.*$
```

...where `''` is an empty string.

For maximum portability you should replace the `\t` in `[ \t]` with a literal `<tab>` character.